# C# LINQ & Parsing Information

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am trying to figure out the easiest method to search a list of objects and to use data from a string to assist with the search. The below is an example object that helps demonstrate what I am trying to do.

```
public class Event {
    public DateTime timestamp;
    public int reason;
    public int data;
    public string comment;
}
```

"comment" holds a bunch of extra information about the specific event however I need to search my list to see if three conditions are met and returning a list of the ones where it is met.

1. data >= 75
2. comment contains the something along the lines of "Dist(6506.1m)"
3. That the number is within the string of the previous step is >= 500

I can do all this via normal coding and using Regular Expresions, but I am trying to figure out if there is a means of transforming it into a single LINQ Query.

Comment: Your `if`s will be converted to `Where`. The rest is almost the same. What is the point you have trouble.

Comment: Can you please explain 3?

Comment: Show regular code and we will transform it to LINQ

Comment: @Tarik really? I didn't know there is a code translation service here.

Comment: @Tarik No you should think about it (topic: encouraging bad questions)

Comment: @EZI On the contrary, I wanted himto come up with some code rather than doing the whole thing for him. You know, there is no absolute measurement on how much effort has been expended by the author of a question. It's often a matter of judgement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can certainly be done with LINQ,

```
var regex = new Regex(@"(Dist\((\d*\.?\d*)m\))");
var result = Events
    .Where(e => e.data >= 75)
    .Select(e => new {Result = regex.Match(e.comment), Event = e})
    .Where(o => double.Parse(o.Result.Groups[2].Value) >= 500)
    .Select(o => o.Event);
```

To be safer, you could even use TryParse inside the Where clause:

```
.Where(o => 
{
    double number;
    double.TryParse(o.Result.Groups[2].Value, out number);
    return number >= 500;
})
```

Comment: This could be made more efficient by using `Select` to run the Regex only once. This code will run the regex twice.

Comment: @IanNewson I have fixed it with your suggestion

Comment: Good, but don't you need to add `e.Success &&` to the `Where` call?

Comment: @IanNewson Your right, nice catch. I just realized, this ends up selecting the match and outputting it to the results. Is there a way to check this and select the original object in the end?

Comment: Yes, in the `Select` create a new anonymous object with both the match and the original object, e.g. `Select(e => new { Match = regex.Match(e.comment), Event = e)`.

Comment: @Cyral, I just did something along the following `Select(e => new { Result = regex.Match(e.comment), Event = e})`

Comment: @7H3LaughingMan That is cool! Never knew that was possible, I'll add it to the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Add a method to your Event class that parses the comment line for Dist(xxxx.xx) such that it returns true if it is found and when xxx is >= 500.

```
public class Event
{
    public DateTime timestamp;
    public int reason;
    public int data;
    public string comment;

    public bool HasDistMiniumum(int min)
    {
       add your regular expression code here that looks for Dist(xxxx) where xxxx is >= min...
    }

// Use this Linq Line...
var matchingItems = EventList.Where(item => item.data >= 75 && item.HasDistMinimum(500));
```

Comment: Yup, this is an excellent answer if he can alter his  Event class.

Comment: If he can't alter the Event class he can add a static Extension class ==> static class EventExt { static bool HasDistMinimum(this Event event, in min) {...} }